# How IllegalArgumentException automatically handled inside 'if' condition

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, illegalargumentexception

I wanted to update the lastModifiedDate to current date and perform some action, only if the current date is greater than lastModifiedDate.

But I was concerned about getting NullPointerException near "`dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated"))`" inside if condition, when executed at the first time because, there is no key-value pair for "lastUpdated" key, yet in the HashMap. Below is the code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class TestDate {

    static HashMap<String, LocalDate> lastModifiedDate = new HashMap<>();
    static int unityResponsesCount;

    public void resetUnityResponsesCount() {
        unityResponsesCount = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate dateToday = LocalDate.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

        if (lastModifiedDate.isEmpty() || dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated"))) {
            lastModifiedDate.put("lastUpdated", dateToday);
            TestDate testDate = new TestDate();
            testDate.resetUnityResponsesCount();
        }
    }

}
```

Before running, I debugged the code and when I inspect only "`dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated"))`", I got,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Partial cannot be null    at
>   org.joda.time.base.AbstractPartial.isAfter(AbstractPartial.java:351)
>     at org.theorem.scan.qa.util.TestDate.main(TestDate.java:25)

But if I inspect complete if statement, `lastModifiedDate.isEmpty() || dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated"))`, I'm getting **"TRUE"**.
If this IF statement yielded Exception, I should have provided separate if conditions with the same assignment inside each of them, `lastModifiedDate.put("lastUpdated", dateToday);`.

I'm just astonished, how IllegalArgumentException is handled automatically inside if condition.

Comment: If `lastModifiedDate.isEmpty()` is true then `dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated"))` is not evaluated.

Comment: Hello @khelwood, Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

This condition

```
(lastModifiedDate.isEmpty() || dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated")))
```

is using the short-circuit OR operator `||`.

That means that `lastModifiedDate.isEmpty()` is evaluated first, and if it is true, `dateToday.isAfter(lastModifiedDate.get("lastUpdated"))` is *not* evaluated, so the exception is not thrown. The whole expression is regarded as true.